# In a API Controller I am trying to put the value of Route in a variable. How do I get the value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How do I get the info for the route ie: api/students or api/emps
var cinfo = RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString(); works pulls controller name "student"
var rinfo = RouteData.Values["Route"].ToString(); - undefined

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/students")] 
[Route("api/emps")]
public class StudentController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ISchoolRepository _repository;

    public StudentController(ISchoolRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository ?? 
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(repository));
    }

    [HttpGet()]
    public IActionResult GetEntTyps(string typ="STU")
    {
        var cinfo = RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString();
        var rinfo = RouteData.Values["Route"].ToString();
        var results = _repository.GetAllEntTyps(typ);
        return Ok(results);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Route` isn't a *route value*, so it's not available in the `RouteData` collection. You can get the value you're looking for from the [`AttributeRouteInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.routing.attributerouteinfo)'s [`Template`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.routing.attributerouteinfo.template#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Routing_AttributeRouteInfo_Template) property:

```
var rinfo = ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.AttributeRouteInfo.Template;
```

Based on your example, `rinfo` will be either `api/students` or `api/emps`, depending on which route template was used for the request.